# options_for_select default selection breaks under passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have the following code that works perfectly in my devl (local) environment, but breaks under passenger (production):

```
     <select name="acp[acp_type]">
    <%= options_for_select ([["Standalone",0] ,["Public", 1],["Private", 2],["Both", 3]],@acp.acp_type) %>
  </select>
```

In development, it generates a dropdown list and selects whatever is in @acp.acp_type.  In production there is a Template error (see below).  If I remove the `,@acp.acp_type` it works fine, but I don't get the value selected.

Here is my gem list (this matches development exactly other than the passenger-related gems):

- abstract (1.0.0)
- actionmailer (3.0.4)
- actionpack (3.0.4)
- activemodel (3.0.4)
- activerecord (3.0.4)
- activeresource (3.0.4)
- activesupport (3.0.4)
- arel (2.0.10)
- attributes (5.0.1)
- builder (2.1.2)
- bundler (1.0.18)
- daemon_controller (1.0.0)
- erubis (2.6.6)
- factory_girl (2.0.5)
- factory_girl_rails (1.1.0)
- fastthread (1.0.7)
- i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
- jquery-rails (1.0.16)
- mail (2.2.19)
- mime-types (1.16)
- mysql (2.8.1)
- mysql2 (0.2.13)
- passenger (3.0.11)
- polyglot (0.3.2)
- prototype (2.0.0)
- rack (1.2.3)
- rack-cache (1.1)
- rack-mount (0.6.14)
- rack-test (0.5.7)
- rails (3.0.4)
- railties (3.0.4)
- rake (0.9.2)
- rdoc (3.9.4)
- rvm (1.9.2)
- thor (0.14.6)
- treetop (1.4.10)
- tzinfo (0.3.29)
- uuidtools (2.1.2)
- will_paginate (3.0.2)

And the error is:
     ActionView::Template::Error (/var/www/html/tpdemo/app/views/acps/_form.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...Both", 3]],@acp.acp_type) );@output_buff...
...                               ^
/var/www/html/tpdemo/app/views/acps/_form.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end 
...Both", 3]],@acp.acp_type) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
...                               ^):
    18: `<select name="acp[acp_type]">`
    19: `<%= options_for_select ([["Standalone",0] ,["Public", 1],["Private", 2],["Both", 3]],@acp.acp_type) %>` 
    20:  `</select>`
    21:  `</div>`
    22:

Answer (score 0):

So the code looks fine, but it's very unlikely that Passenger is the culprit -- more likely the data on your other server is different -- perhaps `@acp.acp_type` is `nil`.  (I think `@acp` is not nil, as otherwise I think you would get a nil error).  Another explanation is that the data schema is outdated -- did you just add this field and still need to run a migration?

Comment: I verified that the schema is the same, and the data is valid.  If I replace the `<select>` tag with   <%= f.label :acp_type, "Type: #{@acp.acp_type}" %> I get the view displayed with a valid value printed out (the error is gone).  So it seems something specific to the options_for_select tag going on here..?

Comment: Hrrm.  Well, it's got to be something silly :-).  These tag helpers are really just convenience methods for generating HTML (select the "show" link after the documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select to see it).  Maybe try using a hash instead of an array (just as a test), e.g. `options_for_select({"Standalone" => "0", "Public" => "1"...}, @acp.acp_type)`, and/or hardcode a value for the selected option to rule out some syntax error.  Something's different on dev vs prod.  Is the local machine Windows?  Newlines?

Comment: Yes- this is very odd indeed, especially considering all my other views, models, controllers work fine.  Both machines are Linux, running same version of ruby/rails. I changed the code to a hash and I hard-coded `:selected => 3`, but got the same error.  Works in dev. I ensured that I restarted Apache each time, and made a change to another page just to make sure changes were showing up on the server.  They are.

Comment: Bizarre.  I got nothin'.  Sorry :-(

Comment: Thanks for trying- at least I'm not missing something obvious.  I tried hard-coding `:disabled =>3` and I get the same error, so it seems to be unrelated to the parameter.  Any parameter causes the problem.  I think everything else is the same, that's why I'm figuring it must be something to do with passenger or it's gems.  I even hooked my development code up to the production database to rule out that avenue with the same result.  I've rebuilt the rails/ruby env with newer versions, to no avail.  Anyone have other ideas?